# Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar'. Received status code 500 from server

Tags: android, gradle

From today I am getting this error.

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar'. Received status code 500 from server: 
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Does anybody have idea? Whats wrong with this. This is coming in my all projects. not for particular one project.

Below is module app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }



     android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "sample-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

//    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.0@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
//    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.Omega-R:OmegaRecyclerView:1.6.15@aar'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13' // Custom Color Picker Dialog
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

Here is Project gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Are you able to access that URL directly?

Comment: No. I can not able to access

Comment: Please edit your question to include both your gradle files

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I think it's a hosting issue that you cant do anything about

Comment: It must be up, because I need to make my app live. I do not know what to do.

Comment: it's back now don't panic :), try it again